# Building Yocto on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: ubuntu, yocto

I'm trying to follow this page:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1079666/How-to-run-Yocto-Linux-OS-in-a-virtual-machine

I've downloaded the Ubuntu 23.04 iso and created a virtual machine in VirtualBox version 7.0.10 r158379 (Qt5.15.2)

I've got as far as:

```
# cd ..
# hob
```

Which results in:

```
Command 'hob' not found, did you mean:
  command 'mob' from snap mob-sh (4.2.0)
  command 'hub' from snap hub (v2.14.2)
  command 'wob' from deb won (0.14.2-1)
  command 'hop' from deb hopenpgp-tools (0.23.7-1)
  command 'hub' from deb hub (2.14.2~ds1-1ubuntu1)
  command 'who' from deb left (3.91-1)
  command 'hnb' from deb hnb (1.9.18+ds1-3)
  command 'hot' from deb hopenpgp-tools (0.23.7-1)
  command 'hoz' from deb how (1.65-3build1)
See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.
```

Comment: This is a very old tutorial, which is in some cases not a problem, but in Yocto-world 7 years is an eternity - Jethro is as old and unsupported as it gets. Also, this version is Python2 based - do you get any warning about this when sourcing the build-env script? Any way, you could try installing python2 and make it the default python (not recommended), install an age-appropriate Ubuntu, like 16.something (once again, not a good idea), or try a tutorial following a newer version of Yocto.

Comment: I've tried installing python2, is there a better link to try and follow ?

Comment: Primarily I would recommend the Yocto project's own [quick start guide](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/brief-yoctoprojectqs/index.html) - though it can be dense for first timers (would still bookmark it, for later). Otherwise, as a next-next-finish tutorial [this](https://linuxconfig.org/yocto-linux-tutorial-basics) doesn't look bad at the first sight.

Comment: Going through this now: https://zatoichi-engineer.github.io/2017/10/02/yocto-on-osx.html

Comment: Generally speaking, if a tutorial uses anything older than Honister, it is recommended to avoid it - it's just too outdated. Even if it uses a Python from this millennia, there were some syntax changes recently in the recipes that obsoleted quite a lot of content on the internet.

Comment: If you are not building for an explicit old machine or setup, then it is recommended to check supported distributions for each Yocto release, and it is highly recommended to use latest LTS releases like `dunfell` `kirkstone` and others